# How to change EditText cursor height?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to change the `EditText` cursor height, does anyone know how?

Answer (score 29):

I had to dig far into the Android source to find the answer to this, but you essentially have to use padding on a custom shape drawable.

note: **only works on API 12 and greater** due to support for `textCursorDrawable`

Use **positive** *top* padding to move the *top* of your cursor **higher**

User **positive** *bottom* padding to move the *bottom* of your cursor **lower**

I usually end up using negative bottom padding to shorten the cursor because the it drops too low below baseline when you increase the line height with `lineSpacingMultiplier` or `lineSpacingExtra`.

**example cursor_red.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <size 
        android:width="2dip" />
    <solid
        android:color="@color/red" />
    <padding 
        android:top="2sp"
        android:bottom="-11sp" />
</shape>
```

This will make a 2dip wide red cursor that is

- 2sp higher (longer) at the top
- 11sp higher (shorter) on the bottom.

Then in your edittext, just specify `android:textCursorDrawable`:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_red" />
```

Relevant Android source code inside **Editor.java** from which I figured out the solution:

```
private void updateCursorPosition(int cursorIndex, int top, int bottom, float horizontal) {
    ...

    mCursorDrawable[cursorIndex].getPadding(mTempRect);

    ...

    mCursorDrawable[cursorIndex].setBounds(left, top - mTempRect.top, left + width,
            bottom + mTempRect.bottom);
}
```

Comment: I have a similar problem where the cursor grows to be as a little bigger than the added imagespan on that line - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21706567/how-can-i-prevent-the-cursor-from-resizing-in-an-edittext-multiautocompletetext , Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 7):

Paddings can be used to control cursor height

**cursor.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <size android:width="2dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/black" />
</shape>
```

**cursor_with_padding.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="7dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/cursor"
        android:top="8dp" />
</layer-list>
```

**layout**

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_with_padding"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the editText style to a custom style

```
<item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/myEditText</item>
```

then use a drawable to set the cursor:

```
<style name="myEditText" parent="@android:parentdetails">
<item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@android:drawable/my_cursor_drawable</item>
<item name="android:height">Height here e.g. 50sp</item> 
</style>
```