# Android - adjust top and bottom padding in EditText when using large fonts (60dp)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext

I am having some problems controlling EditText when I set its textSize to large font, say 60dp. When I do that the cursor becomes huge and even if I set the layout_height to say 80dp it trims the EditText from the top. It seems the padding on top and bottom are impossible to control in large fonts.

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

I want to have a little padding on top and bottom and the value centered vertically and horizontally.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/zip1_1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="0"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="60dp"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"
                    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0"
                    android:includeFontPadding="false"
                    />
```

EDIT - added screenshot

Answer (score 1):

**1-** You should use "sp" instead of "dp" when defining size of text in textview, edittext etc...

**2-** Take a look at this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15236543/8883361

Comment: Thank  you for #1. I will remember that. I already saw #2, tried it and while it did change the size of my cursor the problem remains the same.

Comment: Did you tried it with removing last three lines from your edittext xml? And i assume you already tried paddingtop and paddingbottom in edittext xml as you said?

Comment: Did that and no go :(